# Printing on the several lines repeatedly in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, output, string-literals

I'm working on a project for class that revolves around astronomy and telescope position using Python 3.6.  My project involves printing the telescope's position to the console and updating repeatedly.  I want to have the info printed to the console and overwritten every timestep to keep the user updated about its current position. So far, I've implemented printing out the local time and UTC:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from numpy import array
import sys

#Initial conditions
longitude= 83.6123 #W
latitude= 41.6624 #N
tstep=1/24 #timestep between time calculations
zero_angle=latitude #when telescope is directly up, the angle between telescope and horizon is the latitude.


while stop!=1:
    utc_time,loc_time=datetime.utcnow(),time.ctime()
    print('UTC       :',utc_time,'Local time:',loc_time,flush=True,end='\r')
    #print('Coordinates: ', latitude, ' N',longitude, ' W')
    time.sleep(tstep)
```

Some of the stuff at the top is for later use and isn't relevant yet.  This code currently prints out:

```
UTC       : 2018-04-27 20:41:41.981367 Local time: Fri Apr 27 16:41:41 2018
```

and updates that output every 1/24th of a second.  What I'd like to do is have this happen with multiple lines (so several lines update every timestep, and get overwritten).  The flush=True and end='\r' I found in other threads, but applying this to a separate print statement overwrites the first line.  Is there a way to have several independent lines that are all updated each timestep? Thanks!

Comment: Though it isn't supported in all terminals, the `\033[A` character means to go up one line. You can also put a number between the bracket and A to specify how many lines to go up.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the `curses` module. It is an interface to the classic `curses` library for doing cursor movement on a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

looks like I found a solution!

If you import "clear_output" from IPython.display you can allow the console to refresh after each iteration with updated information.  The resulting code:

```
while im_still_presenting==True:
    utc_time,loc_time=datetime.utcnow(),time.ctime()
    print('UTC        :',utc_time,'Julian Day:',JD(utc_time),flush=True)
    print('Local time :',loc_time,flush=True)
    print('Coordinates: ', latitude, ' N',longitude, ' E',flush=True)

    time.sleep(tstep)
    clear_output(wait=True)
```

will print this to the console:

```
UTC        : 2018-04-29 15:17:30.667045 Julian Day: 2458237.5
Local time : Sun Apr 29 11:17:30 2018
Coordinates:  41.6624  N -83.6123  E
```

and update the UTC and local time fields every timestep.  Thanks for your help everybody :)